# Passing variables in uiautomator

Tags: java, android-uiautomator

So this is my current structure:

```
 public class PassingVariables extends UiautomatorTestCase{

    int variable1;
    int variable2;

 public void setUp() throws UiObjectNotFound{

       ///Set up

 }

 public void testSetVariable(){
        variable1 = 6;
        variable2 = 7;
        System.out.printlin(variable1 +" " + variable2);
 }
 public void testReadVariable(){
        System.out.println(variable1);
        System.out.println(variable2);
 }
```

I am expecting this to output, `6`, `7`, then `6` and `7`. But it is outputting `6`, `7` then `0` and `0`.

Comment: These methods are called via command line. `public class PassingVariables...` IS my main. These are uiautomation tests for android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely constructor is not called once, but n times if they are n tests. 
You expect one shared instance, but in reality, there are n instances.

That makes sense, since for the `testReadVariable()`, variables are not set in there, so you end up with default values that are `0` and `0`.

Test should be independent, and you expect them to be dependent...